# example of an application that uses a JBDC

Tags: jdbc

i want to practice my programming skills and want to design a program that implements a JBDC, can someone give me some ideas of some fun beginner level programs can i design?

Comment: why not use a search engine: "JDBC beginner tutorial"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
As a beginner level try [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html) . Then take a scenario like write a web/desktop application for employees to manage their information like addresse, timings,mobile number. Ultimately it's nothing but crud application.